# Best way to create a merged JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

in my Java web app I does generate a report, one page every customer detected.

I had create a single JasperReport, and if the list of customer is more than 1 I'll would like to concat the reports generated.

This is my code:

```
if(myList.size()==1) {
        JasperPrint jp = reportGenerated(myList.get(0).getCustomer());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jp, bos);

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }else {
        for(Object s: myList) {
                                jasperPrints.add(reportGenerated(s.getCustomer()));
            }
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(jasperPrints));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/lettera.pdf")); 
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();

        configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true); 
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();


    }
```

I want to obtain the merged PDF, but i don't find the function to export a List of **JasperPrint** in **ByteArrayOutputStream**.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There's no need to concatenate the report output. Change the report to take a collection of customers, instead. Have the report control pagination and you'll find that the output for all customers is concatenated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

```
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/lettera.pdf"))
```

with:

```
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(bos));
```

And add the return statement:

```
 return bos.toByteArray();
```

I think this solution can help you.